# Is it possible to use a double value in mouse_event in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, mouseevent

I need to use a value of type double and move the mouse by a given value. Unfortunately double is not compatible with mouse_event, and only int is compatible. In C++ as well as AHK it worked without any problem. Is it possible to use double or any value that allows decimal digits in mouse_event in any way? I tried editing

```
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

to

```
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, double dx, double dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

and then the mouse immediately went to the bottom left corner of the screen so this solution doesn't work. I also tried converting value to INT type, but then it doesn't move because the value after conversion sets to 0.

Comment: From the docs: "Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead."

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The [function signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) is fixed, and you don't get to change it just because.

If you want to use sort-of fractional values, operate the function in `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` mode. As long as your display is less than 65536 pixels wide or high, this allows you to pass coordinates with sub-pixel precision.

Comment: With `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` this doesn't work too. There's the same problem as it was with `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE`.

Comment: Since you never explained the problem you were trying to solve, it's hard to help with that. It's also impossible to make statements about code we cannot see.

Comment: Problem I want to solve is that I cannot move the mouse by a fractional value via win32api. Line of code at which the problem occurs: `mouse_event(0x0001, 20 * modifier, 26 * modifier, 0, 0);`, the modifier must be expressed as a fractional number to make everything as accurate as possible, currently `double modifier = 0.84`. In C++ this was possible, but not anymore in C#.

Comment: *"In C++ this was possible"* - No. C++ needs to pass integer values into `mouse_event` like any other language interfacing with this API. You have misdiagnosed the issue and are now looking for a solution in the wrong place. Regardless, this proposed answer answers the question that was asked. If you meant to ask a different question click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.